# How do I find the key code of a character in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, keypress

Microsoft provides a [documentation for key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.71).aspx) of characters. For example, one can find that the key code for the delete key is 8 whereas the add key (+) has the key code 107. In a Windows Forms Application I'm trying to create a text box that will only accept digits and the plus sign (+). To do this I have implemented the following code:

```
private void ansBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   char ch = e.KeyChar;
   if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 107) e.Handled = true;
}
```

The code successfully disallows all input except for digits and deletion, but to my surprise blocks the use of the plus sing (+). This leads me to believe that "107" is not the key code for the plus sign in C# or that I've implemented the key codes incorrectly. Is there a way to find the key codes of characters programmatically similarly to how variable types can be identified so that the key code of the plus character can be determined? Alternatively, have I done something incorrectly when trying to implement the above described text box functionality?

Comment: You could probably use a masked text box instead, or checking the `KeyCode` instead of the `KeyChar` you are checking now... If you check the `KeyChar`, try checking for `+` instead of `107`.

Comment: Keycode <> char! Keycode is an `enum`. Why not test `ch != '+'`

Comment: You probably want to use KeyDown event to filter not KeyPress. The KeyDown event args contain the key code not only the character. However you will have to let other keys pass through like arrow keys which don't raise the KeyPress event.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you. Using `ch != '+'` fixes it all.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyCode` and `KeyChar` is not the same.

`KeyCode` is a property of [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) and provides data for the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events. It has the type `Keys`, which is an `enum`.

`KeyChar` is a property of [`KeyPressEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and provides data for the `KeyPress` event. It is a `char`.

The numeric codes of the two are often different.

You can simply test for the plus sign like this

```
ch != '+'
```

C# has an [escape sequnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for Backspace ( `'\b' == (char)8` )

```
if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != '\b' && ch != '+') e.Handled = true;
```